# sending selected field to another react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am receiving my `API` data in `react`. I am sending same `data` to another component to `download` the excel file.

```
  const [data,setData] = useState([]);
  const fetchDataForExcel = async()=>{
        const {data}= await axios.get( env.resourceServerUrl+"/payment/data");
        setData(data);
       
    }
```

I am sending this data to another component to create excel file.

```
 <div><ExportToExcel apiData={data} fileName={fileName} /></div>
```

actually my `data` containes many field like `ID, SSN, Name` etc. I want to send selected field from `data` , not all the field. what changes should I do?

Comment: Your apiData should be type "object" and than give apiData={data.yourProperty}

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "filed" "filed" is a verb, what have you filed and where did you file those?

Comment: Hello Mark I mean FIELD. means if we have 10 properties under data, I want to write only 5 in the excel file. so I want to send only those 5 properties(fields) to <ExportToExcel> component.

Comment: I think what you should do here @ShrutiSharma, is to send the entire data to the `ExportToExcel` component. Along with that, you should send another configuration/prop that contains the field names that are to be included in the excel sheet. That way your component is going to be highly re-usable and the logic to filter out the not required fields will be required to be written only once, i.e. in the `ExportToExcel` component. You can use `pick` method by `lodash` to pick up the required fields from the data.

Comment: What have you tried on your own already? What exactly is the issue? Stackoverflow isn't a code writing service. Please update your post to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for what you are trying to do and clearly explain any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**VIEW RECREATION**

Setting a property on the child component will cause it to get recreated and this can lose its existing data when you set new data.

**VIEW MODELS**

One way to deal with this is to use `view model` objects inside the `props` object. This keeps hold of your data even when views get created. See [this view creation](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/blob/master/spa/src/app/app.tsx#L316) for an example of how view models are passed in.

**DATA COMPOSITION**

In fact if you have an entry point `AppViewModel` it can then create child view models, and this pattern can easily be extended in a tidy manner.

Have a look at [these classes](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/tree/master/spa/src/app) for how it all fits together. React has some other state management solutions but I quite like this one.

Answer (score 2):

If you already know the name of the property on the object you want, then you should be able to send it with;

`<div><ExportToExcel apiData={data.foo} fileName={fileName} /></div>`

Alternatively, you could send the entire data object, then inside `<ExportToExcel>` you could access the property from the prop, eg/
`props.apiData.foo`. (
To me, the name "apiData" suggests all the data returned from an API not just a single property.)

Comment: actually inside the <ExportToExcel > I dont want to mention the field name because this would be generic component which multiple component will use for file download

Answer (score 2):

Just create new obj with fields you need like this

```js
<ExportToExcel 
  apiData={{ sheet1: data.sheet1, otherstuff: data.other }}
  fileName={fileName} 
/>
```

or better (if ExportToExcel is not provided by some library)

```js
<ExportToExcel 
  sheet1={data.sheet1} 
  otherstuff={data.other}
  fileName={fileName} 
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't destructure data inside `ExportToExcel`  component, you've got 2 options:

1. If you'll just be using certain fields in data throughout, just destructure it inside `fetchDataForExcel` function, pass only those to `setData`.

   ```
   const fetchDataForExcel = async()=>{
      const {data}= await axios.get( env.resourceServerUrl+"/payment/data");
      const {field1, field2, field3} = data;
      setData({field1, field2, field3});
    }
   ```

   Then just pass data directly

   ```
     <div><ExportToExcel apiData={data} fileName={fileName} /></div>
   ```
2. Selectively pass the props:

   ```
    <div><ExportToExcel apiData={{field1: data.field1, field2: data.field2}} 
    fileName={fileName} /></div>
   ```

Let me know if it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Destructuring would be a best option there as you want selected files destructure data you need and then pass as a props to child component.

```
 const [data,setData] = useState([]);
  const fetchDataForExcel = async()=>{
        const {data}= await axios.get( env.resourceServerUrl+"/payment/data");
        setData(data); 
    } 
const {requiredField} = data;
 <div><ExportToExcel requiredField={requiredField} fileName={fileName} /></div>
```